# Cant get items from external list

Tags: list, 2013, event-receivers, external-content-type, external-list

I have an External list based on an External Content Type that is connected to Dynamics CRM.

In an event receiver (C#), I successfully get an SPList instance that is able to print the 'Title' and 'Created' properties.

However when I print the property 'ItemCount', i get "0 items". I know that there is a couple of hundred items in the list so something is not right.

When I try a SPQuery against the list, I get and exception when trying to use the returned SPListItemCollection.

What may be the cause of this problem?

Comment: whats the exception?

Comment: I cant get any information from the Exception object in catch method. The ex.Message and ex.StackTrace returns null

Comment: ok is it possible to debug the code? put a break point at ItemCount?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use the external list on my development environment. So I can only try the solution on the production environment and therefore not debug.